# Passing a vector to seq() in R

Tags: r

So here is my question:

Why does this happen:

> x <- c(9,5)
>
> seq(x)

[1] 1 2

Why do I get 1 and 2 , shouldn't I get an error?

Here are few more examples:

> x <- c(9,5,9)
>
> seq(x)

[1] 1 2 3

> x <- c(9,5,9,9)
>
> seq(x)

[1] 1 2 3 4

Comment: Why you should get an error ??. Did you check `?seq`??

Comment: The help file for `seq` is useful for explaining this behavior. In the help file for [`seq`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seq.html), one of the methods is to use `along.with`, which "generates the integer sequence `1, 2, ..., length(along.with)`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me show you a part of help for `seq` accessible via `?seq` :

```
Typical usages are


seq(from)

The fifth form generates the sequence 1, 2, ..., length(from) 
(as if argument along.with had been specified), 
unless the argument is numeric of length 1 when it is interpreted as 1:from 
(even for seq(0) for compatibility with S). 
Using either seq_along or seq_len is much preferred 
(unless strict S compatibility is essential).
```

So you won't get an error if you try to use

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
seq(x)
```

, but of course you will get an error if you try to use more than one parameter

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
seq(x,3)
```

Comment: But I still didn't understand why this happens with no errors and I get sequence of numbers from 1 to the length of the vector passed, this is what I mean : > x <- c(9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9)
> seq(x)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

Comment: It's the way the function seq is implemented.